# QUITE _id of array when send post to mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I need help to create the db with this model.
(its for a api mongoose and express, I can use mongoshell or mongoose schema).

```
{
"hotels" : [{
"name" : "Hotel Emperador",
"stars" : "3",
"images" :[....],
"price" : "1596",
},
...]
}
```

but when I post the array to MongoDB automatically create `_id:""` for my array, can I remove this? I need `_id` but for my documents inside array, I obtain something like this :

```
{"_id": "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a", 
  "hotels":[
    {
    "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
    "stars" : 4,
    "price" : 1596,
    "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co.jpg",
    "id": 1
    },...]}
```

I need something like this, because it's very difficult for me. find to documents with the previous code.

```
{
"hoteles": [
    {
        "_id": "5e1217b81c9d440000632fd7",
        "nombre": "Hotel Sonesta",
        "direccion": "Cerritos",
        "telefono": "3152020",
        "estrellas": "5",
        "precio": "850000",
        "imagenes": "https://i.ibb.co/t2Hc8c4/Hotel-Sonesta.jpg"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1218211c9d440000632fd8",
        "nombre": "Hotel Soratama",
        "direccion": "Centro",
        "telefono": "3204545",
        "estrellas": "4",
        "precio": "540000",
        "imagenes": "https://i.ibb.co/vcyqQSf/Soratama.jpg"
    },..]}
```

I know the model schema can be helpful but tried and didn't work
Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly do you need ? So do you need `_id` in each object of hotels array or need to remove it on inserts ? Is that what this question is about ?

Comment: i need _id only for my objects embedded no for my array.

Comment: Do you mean you wanted to insert objects with `_id` generated or assigned by you ?

Comment: I need mongo db not to automatically generate id my array, but for my nested objects yes .it's possible?

Comment: sorry for the delay, i try with your code and recibed this "message": "document must have an _id before saving"  // with {_id: "false"}  into mainSchema don't allows request post into mongodb.

Comment: I’ve tested it, they’re working fine not able to understand what your talking about..

Comment: are you  using mongodb atlas or local db? i am use atlas.

Comment: Altas, it doesn't matter, So issues do you've now ?

Comment: well i have a question, why dont use module.exports in your code?
you use  
const MainColModel = mongoose.model('yourActualCollectionName', mainSchema, 'yourActualCollectionName');
// i change your MainColModel for module.exports,  is it wrong?
look:
 https://pastebin.com/raw/TcFUWQyp
my post  request json it is:
https://pastebin.com/raw/DcJwRPp3

Comment: Yes we can use `module.exports` & split code into multiple files, what exactly is the issue now ?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should be like this :

```
 // Option : 1
 const hotelesSchema = new Schema({
    "_id" : Number, // This is optional now
    "nombre": String,
    "direccion": String,
    "telefono": String,
    "estrellas": String,
    "precio": String,
    "imagenes": String
}) 

 /** Option : 2

(Or if you don't even need it at all -> _id will not be created automatically or even if you pass it won't be inserted)

const hotelesSchema = new Schema({
    "nombre": String,
    "direccion": String,
    "telefono": String,
    "estrellas": String,
    "precio": String,
    "imagenes": String
}, { _id: false }) */


const mainSchema = new Schema({
    hoteles: [ hotelesSchema ]
}, { _id: false }); // Adding { _id: false } will not create _id on top level.

const MainColModel = mongoose.model('yourActualCollectionName', mainSchema, 'yourActualCollectionName');
```

**Code :**

```
const mainColObj = new MainColModel({
            hoteles: [{
                "_id": 123, // If you don't pass it here it won't be created.
                "nombre": "Hotel Sonesta",
                "direccion": "Cerritos",
                "telefono": "3152020",
                "estrellas": "5",
                "precio": "850000",
                "imagenes": "https://i.ibb.co/t2Hc8c4/Hotel-Sonesta.jpg"
            },
            {
                "_id": 456,
                "nombre": "Hotel Soratama",
                "direccion": "Centro",
                "telefono": "3204545",
                "estrellas": "4",
                "precio": "540000",
                "imagenes": "https://i.ibb.co/vcyqQSf/Soratama.jpg"
            }]
        })

let dbResp = await mainColObj.save();
```

**Result :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1bee2a39ae20e06dc116db"), // Won't be created if you add , { _id: false } to mainSchema
    "hoteles" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 123, // You don't see _id in Option : 2
            "nombre" : "Hotel Sonesta",
            "direccion" : "Cerritos",
            "telefono" : "3152020",
            "estrellas" : "5",
            "precio" : "850000",
            "imagenes" : "https://i.ibb.co/t2Hc8c4/Hotel-Sonesta.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 456, // You don't see _id in Option : 2
            "nombre" : "Hotel Soratama",
            "direccion" : "Centro",
            "telefono" : "3204545",
            "estrellas" : "4",
            "precio" : "540000",
            "imagenes" : "https://i.ibb.co/vcyqQSf/Soratama.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: @Steven Ramirez : If you need samething to happen top level i.e; if you don't need `"_id" : ObjectId("5e1bee2a39ae20e06dc116db")` from above `Result` then you need to add `{ _id: false }` to `mainSchema`

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like this :

**Model :**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var hotelSchema = new Schema({
    _id: false, //remove this line , it will automatic generate the _id for document which is not harmfull for you case
    hoteles: [{
        _id : true, // even if we do not mention the key _id , it will auto generate the unique _id for every object in the array of hotels
        nombre: {type : String} ,
        direccion: {type : String},
        telefono: {type : String}, 
        estrellas: {type : String},
        precio: {type : String}, 
        imagenes: {type : String}, 
    }],

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('hotel' , hotelSchema);
```

Try out this code

Comment: hello, i tried your code but my VS(editor say the _id no its valid with true, then i change for Number its works, but when i send post request:
 "message": "document must have an _id before saving"

Comment: So now there will be _id of document as well as of your `hotels` array . which is correct so  you can acess all the documents. @StevenRamirez